# How to correctly check through an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code

```
def gen_code(codeLength):
    symbols = ('ABCDEF')
    code = random.sample(symbols, k=codeLength)
    return str(code)

def print_code(code):
    i = 0
    while i < len(code):
        print(code[i])
        i += 1

code = gen_code(codeLength)
print("The code is " + code)
convCode = code[0] + code[1] + code[2] + code[3]
print(convCode)
```

So I basically want to generate a random string from the letters I have provided and then check if the user guesses a correct entry in that string (I'm trying to make mastermind). The issue I have is checking to see if the user's guess is in the code which is generated.

This is what my code outputs:
[image: Output]

Why is my `convCode` variable printing ['E' and not EAFB?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. In addition, please paste the text output of your code into the question, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: Because you ask it to give you the first 4 characters in the string `code`. You want the characters in a `list` instead, I presume

Comment: Yes i know @Uvar. I want the first 4 characters which i presumed would be the first and only 4 i have put into the array. Which was the code. I never added the symbols [ or ' to the array

Comment: `convCode =''.join(code[:4)`

Comment: Please provide indentation for the code, otherwise, it is difficult to understand.

Comment: I think you should change symbols to `symbols = ['A','B','C','D','E','F',]` instead of `symbols = ('ABCDEF')`, though since it works you dont really have to change this.

Comment: @JamieMcClenaghan let me state it more strongly. The first four characters of your code are, in sequence `'['`  `"'"` `"E"` `"'"` . As it is a `string`

Comment: @Uvar but where are the brackets and apostrophes coming from? As i only gave the option for ABCDEF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is returned as a `list` instead of a `string`, you can access the individual letters of the code in the manner you want to.

```
import random
codeLength=4
def gen_code(codeLength):
    symbols = ('ABCDEF')
    code = random.sample(symbols, k=codeLength)
    return code
def print_code(code):
    i = 0
    while i < len(code):
        print(code[i])
        i += 1

code = gen_code(codeLength)
print("The code is " + str(code))
convCode = code[0] + code[1] + code[2] + code[3]
print(convCode)
```

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for explaining it :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `gen_code` function you convert the list to a string before you return it:

```
def gen_code(codeLength):
    symbols = ('ABCDEF')
    code = random.sample(symbols, k=codeLength)

    # This converts it to a string, rather than leaving it as a list
    # which is presumably what you want.
    return str(code)
```

So later in your code:

```
convCode = code[0] + code[1] + code[2] + code[3]
```

Gives you the first four characters of that string which are exactly ['E'

Try changing `gen_code` to this:

```
def gen_code(codeLength):
    symbols = ('ABCDEF')
    code = random.sample(symbols, k=codeLength)
    return code
```

Answer (score 0):

`code` is a list use slicing to get the required result which will give you flexibility as you need not write hardcoded list indices each time.

```
import random
def gen_code(codeLength):
    symbols = ('ABCDEF')
    code = random.sample(symbols, k=codeLength)
    return code

def print_code(code):

    i = 0
    while i < len(code):
        print(code[i])
        i += 1

code = gen_code(5)
print("The code is " + str(code))
convCode =code[:4]
print(convCode)
```